# Можно ли в Godot в переменную скрипта в редакторе засунуть Node из сцены

Tags: c#, godot

Есть скрипт

```
public class SwitchHandler : Node
{
    public Node traps;
   
}
```

Я его на node в сцене вешаю. У меня переменная появляется в редакторе. По идее я теперь могу node из сцены туда засунуть но я не могу туда его засунуть. Так как это вообще работает я могу или это проблема баг я не знаю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]